# LUIS Intent not recognized by bot

Tags: node.js, azure-language-understanding

**EDIT**

So sorry everyone, it was just due to a missing comma after the name of the intent. I am so sorry x:

---

I am recently creating a chat bot using Microsoft Bot Framework (`botbuilder v3.14.0`), Node.js (`v8.9.4`) and LUIS.

I am able to successfully 'recognize' some intents in the bot, and return the desired results, but for some intents, the bot doesn't seem to be able to pick up the intents, even though the results from LUIS is pointing towards the correct one.

I have tried testing using the LUIS testing blade and entering the query directly after the endpoint URL in chrome. Both methods will return me the same and correct intent. A sample result from the endpoint URL method is as below:

```
{
  "query": "why do you exist",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "bot-existence",
    "score": 0.597947
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "bot-existence",
      "score": 0.597947
    },
    {
      "intent": "bot-joke",
      "score": 0.04189388
    },
    {
      "intent": "Exit",
      "score": 0.0182088781
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.0164906159
    },
    {
      "intent": "Cancel",
      "score": 0.009767669
    },
    {
      "intent": "Stop",
      "score": 0.009608646
    },
    {
      "intent": "bot-age",
      "score": 0.009238302
    },
    {
      "intent": "Greeting",
      "score": 0.008374314
    },
    {
      "intent": "bot-name",
      "score": 0.00683666952
    },
    {
      "intent": "Help",
      "score": 0.00357789616
    },
    {
      "intent": "StartOver",
      "score": 0.00262053218
    },
    {
      "intent": "checkDBStatus",
      "score": 0.002412489
    },
    {
      "intent": "refreshSchema",
      "score": 1.35339326E-06
    },
    {
      "intent": "checkDutyPerson",
      "score": 5.41015623E-08
    }
  ],
  "entities": []
}
```

In this case, the bot should be able to pick out the `bot-existence` intent and execute this code:

```
intents.matches('bot-existence' [
    function (session) {
        console.log('bot-existence Intent');

        session.beginDialog('bot-existDialog');
    }
]);
```

but it doesn't. It works for the other intents though, such as `bot-age`, `bot-joke` and `checkDBStatus`. The codes for these intent are the same as the one above for `bot-existence`, just edited to fit the intents appropriately. I have also published the LUIS app multiple times, just in case, but to no avail.

Any idea why?

Comment: What are the scores for utterances that successfully trigger `bot-age`, `bot-joke`, etc? Have you tried decreasing the intent score threshold for your `IntentDialog`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, did you publish your luis after adding the `bot-existence` intent?

Comment: @StevenG., thanks for your reply. `bot-age` with 'what is your age' is `0.8824824`, `bot-joke` with 'tell me a joke' is `0.277950644`. How do I decrease the intent score threshold?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, thanks for your reply. I did publish the luis app, and checked it and published it again a few times, in fact.

Comment: On your intent dialog instantiation, you can pass in the following settings to change the threshold `{intentThreshold: <some-num>}`. I also recommend adding generic utterances like "tell me a joke" to your LUIS model. That utterance seems generic enough, so its lower score should be improved.

Comment: @StevenG., ooo I shall try it out. 'tell me a joke' is actually one of the 4 utterances I have entered for `bot-joke`. I will try to think of more utterances to train it. However, even with the lower score, `bot-joke` doesn't have any issues though. I am able to run the my desired codes properly. :/

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this question?

Comment: @StevenG., I have yet to find a solution, but moved on to the other parts of my chat bot development first. Hopefully I'll be able to solve it once i'm done with those other parts.

Comment: I saw your edit and then looked again at your code :) Could you add your own answer to the question and mark it as answered? I'm glad you figured it out, sorry I didn't catch that!

Comment: @StevenG. Thanks for checking back! I'm glad I caught this error, so careless of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So sorry guys, all I was missing was a comma in the code, right next to the intent name ('bot-existence'). Edited code segment as below!

```
intents.matches('bot-existence', [
    function (session) {
        console.log('bot-existence Intent');

        session.beginDialog('bot-existDialog');
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, using [triggerAction](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS):

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
// Add the recognizer to the bot
bot.recognizer(recognizer);

bot.dialog('bot-existence', [

  function (session, args) {
        console.log('bot-existence Intent');
        session.beginDialog('bot-existDialog');
    }      
]).triggerAction({matches:'bot-existence'});
```

Comment: While this is a valid approach to using LUIS inside of a bot (in fact I also recommend users plug their recognizers into the bot instead of using an `IntentDialog`), it doesn't address the fact that the user's code for other intents do work.

Comment: @SarthakSerivastava, thanks for your reply. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to do this, since I would rather just use intents from luis to recognise and deal with as much user input as I can think of.

Comment: @belcsy, their approach is valid for using LUIS :) it's just a different approach from using the `IntentDialog` class, we have an example that uses this approach which can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-naturalLanguage/app.js#L82)

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava, @ Steven G. - ooo, my bad, I did not know about that.